# Program that solves mechanics diagram problems

Tags: artificial-intelligence, decision-problem, mathematical-programming

There is a program, BEATRIX, that can understand textbook physics problems specified by a combination of English text and a diagram. The result of the understanding process is a unified internal model that represents information derived from both the text and the diagram.

Here is a diagram problem and the diagram that Beatrix creates in order to solve it: [image]

The problem is that I cant find this program anywhere in the net, so I would like to know if anyone knows a similar program to this one, i.e. a program that is given a mechanical diagram and solves it.

For example, I could give this diagram to the program:

[image]
and it should be able to find the rate of change of beat period of this system. If there isnt a program like this, I would like to know if anyone could help me with ideas in order to create my own program similar to BEATRIX.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Software requests are borderline regarding their topicality.

Comment: http://ai.stackexchange.com

Comment: Cross-posted: http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/72083/755, http://stackoverflow.com/q/43034303/781723.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a request for software, not a question about computer science.